# Docker container always returns code 200 and content-type text/html

Tags: laravel, docker

I use docker and wsl for development on laravel, I ran into the problem that no matter what response settings I would specify in route, the response code 200 and content-type text/html are always loaded

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $response = response()
        ->json(['123' => 'tests'], 422);

    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
});
```

Where `return $response->headers->all()` results to:

[image]

[image]

nginx [image]

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with this problem for a day and eventually accidentally deleted the container and reassembled it.
in the end, everything worked!!!

Comment: Good that you found a solution, but this answer is comment-level, and does not even provide any info on "how to reassemble or delete?".